# loading .so file react-native

Tags: react-native, loadlibrary, .so

I'm trying to load a .so file with my react-native project using the Native Modules.
I'm loading the library with the LoadLibrary func and i am not able to envoke the funtions inside.
However, i have opened a regular java project in android studio and i was able to load the library perfectly.

Any ideas?

[image: Error Image]

[image: library load]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what worked for me was adding this two files where is the MainActivity.java class. You have to change the package name of both classes to  *com.solo_test*

1- https://github.com/CassieLuoli/react-native-smartconnection/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/luoli/smartconnection/SmartConfigHelper.java

2- https://github.com/CassieLuoli/react-native-smartconnection/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/mediatek/demo/smartconnection/JniLoader.java
*don't forget to change de name of the library on JniLoader.java class*

Finally you need to invoke  SmartConfigHelper.init(); in MainActivity for load the library